# how to send a text with a send button to text field on swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, text, send

I really new. all I want to do is send in the text I got on the password field as a secure text to the text field if that's possible. kind of like sending a text but with the secure text. the secure button just lets you see what is inside. I got that to work but I don't know how to transfer the information from one place to the other. do I create a function? Im sorry im a complete noob.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
    return scrollView
}()

private let secureButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Secure", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .link
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget( self, action: #selector(securebuttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
    
}()

let sendButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.addTarget( self, action: #selector(sendButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

let textView = UITextView()

private let passwordField: UITextField = {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.autocapitalizationType = .none
    field.autocorrectionType = .no
    field.returnKeyType = .done
    field.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    field.layer.borderWidth = 1
    field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    field.placeholder = "Password"
    field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 0))
    field.leftViewMode = .always
    field.backgroundColor = .white
    field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    
    return field
}()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    view.backgroundColor = .gray
    
    
    
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(passwordField)
    scrollView.addSubview(secureButton)
    scrollView.addSubview(textView)
    scrollView.addSubview(sendButton)

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    scrollView.frame = view.bounds
    
    passwordField.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                             y: 100,
                             width: scrollView.width-60,
                             height: 52)
    secureButton.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                                y: passwordField.bottom+10 ,
                             width: scrollView.width-60,
                             height: 30)
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                            y: secureButton.bottom+10 ,
                         width: scrollView.width-60,
                         height: 30)
    sendButton.frame = CGRect(x: 30,
                              y: textView.bottom+10 ,
                           width: scrollView.width-60,
                           height: 30)

}
    
@objc func securebuttonTapped() {
    let text = passwordField
    text.isSecureTextEntry = !text.isSecureTextEntry
}

@objc func sendButtonTapped() {
    let text = passwordField
    textView.inputView = text
    print("send button tapped")
}
```

}

Comment: Send message where? to another device? or to some other view controller? If some other device u mean using already existsing app like iMessage or whats app or plain text? or you wanna build that capability? Are u making a complete chat app? if yes u need to send the text to your server and your server will send it to recipients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Swift 5***

if you want to pass the data in the same controller its very simple. just asign the text to the textField on button Pressed

```
  var textField = UITexField()
    
  @objc func sendButtonTapped() {
    // here you will assign the text you got from the password field to watever textfield you want, whether it is secure text or simple text.
    
        textField.text = passwordField.text
        print("send button tapped")
    }
```

if you want to pass that text to some other ViewController you need to send like this

```
  let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: 
  nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! 
  YourViewController

  // here you will assign the text to the variable from other viewcontroller you 
  want to. 

  vc.text = "Enter the text here"
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: thank you. simple solution but I couldn't see it. it worked. thank you so much